# Selecting the the last row in a partition in HIVE

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table t1:

```
c1 | c2 | c3| c4
1    1    1   A
1    1    2   B
1    1    3   C
1    1    4   D
1    1    4   E
1    1    4   F
2    2    1   A
2    2    2   A
2    2    3   A
```

I want to select the last row of each c1, c2 pair. So (1,1,4,F) and (2,2,3,A) in this case. My idea is to do something like this:

```
create table t2 as
select *, row_number() over (partition by c1, c2 order by c3) as rank
from t1

create table t3 as
select a.c1, a.c2, a.c3, a.c4
from t2 a
inner join
(select c1, c2, max(rank) as maxrank
 from t2
 group by c1, c2
 )
on a.c1=b.c1 and a.c2=b.c1
where a.rank=b.maxrank
```

Would this work? (Having environment issues so can't test myself)

Comment: mysql has no `row_number` function.

Comment: Edited to remove mysql tag, sorry about that.

Comment: No clue about hiveql, but I guess you should be able to modify `row_number()` to have it order by descending order. Then you can just select the rows with `rank=1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a subquery:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (partition by c1, c2 order by c3 desc) as rank
      from t1 
     ) t1
where rank = 1;
```

Note the use of `desc` for the `order by`.

Comment: order by c4 desc is also required i feel.

Comment: But since we have identical c3's, wouldn't it be selecting the row (1,1,4,D)? Also, c4 column isn't necessarily ordered. @vkp

Comment: @Danzo . . . This query arbitrarily chooses one of the rows with the maximum `c3` value.  The question doesn't quite seem to explain what that means.  Your code only uses `c3` for the comparison.  If `c4` is part of the comparison, just use `order by c3 desc, c4 desc`, but I'm not sure that is your intention.

Comment: Try this:

     select t1.* from (
     Select *
         , rank() over (partition by c1, c2 order by c3 desc, c4 desc)
         from t1 ) t1
     where rank = 1;